# I want to fetch perticular node it in java using cypher query but i can't fetch it

Tags: jsp, servlets, cypher

I want to fetch perticular node it in java using cypher query but i can't fetch it.
and at debbuging time debbuger return from particular for loop in fetchNodes() method.
i can't undarstand it properly .

class :NewCypherQuery(bean)

```
public class NewCypherQuery {
private static final String DB_PATH = "/var/lib/neo4j/data/";
private static String resultString, columnsString, nodeResult, rows = "",
        query;
private static ExecutionResult result;
private static ExecutionEngine engine;
private static GraphDatabaseService db;
private static Node amad = null,pari=null,sona=null;
private static Relationship rel;

public static void callAllMethods() {
    clearDbPath();
    setUp();
    createNodes();
    // fetchNodes();
    matchData();

}

private static void setUp() {
    db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
    engine = new ExecutionEngine(db);

}

private static void createNodes() {
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx();) {

        amad = db.createNode();
        amad.setProperty("name", "Amad");
        amad.setProperty("age", 24);
        amad.setProperty("edu", "mscit");

        pari = db.createNode();
        pari.setProperty("name", "Pari");
        pari.setProperty("age", 20);
        pari.setProperty("edu", "mscit");

        sona = db.createNode();
        sona.setProperty("name", "Sona");
        sona.setProperty("age", 21);
        sona.setProperty("edu", "mscit");

        rel=amad.createRelationshipTo(pari, RelTypes.KNOWS);
        rel.setProperty("rel", "friend");
        rel=pari.createRelationshipTo(sona, RelTypes.KNOWS);
        rel.setProperty("rel", "friend");

        /*query = "CREATE (amad:User1 { name: 'Amad1',age : 20,education : 'Mscit' }),(pari:User1 { name : 'Pari1' }),(sona:User1 { name : 'Sona1'}),(amad)-[:FRIEND]->(pari),(pari)-[:FRIEND]->(sona)";
        result = engine.execute(query);*/
        System.out.println("Nodes created.....");
        tx.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void fetchNodes() {
    try (Transaction ignored = db.beginTx();) {
        result = engine
                .execute("start n=node(*) where n.name = 'Rita' return n, n.name");
        // END SNIPPET: execute
        // START SNIPPET: items
        Iterator<Node> n_column = result.columnAs("n");

        for (Node node : IteratorUtil.asIterable(n_column)) {
            // note: we're grabbing the name property from the node,
            // not from the n.name in this case.
            nodeResult = node + ": " + node.getProperty("name");
            System.out.println(nodeResult.length());
        }

        List<String> columns = result.columns();
        // END SNIPPET: columns
        // the result is now empty, get a new one
        result = engine
                .execute("start n=node(*) where n.name = 'Rita' return n, n.name");
        // START SNIPPET: rows
        for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
            for (Entry<String, Object> column : row.entrySet()) {
                rows += column.getKey() + ": " + column.getValue() + "; ";
            }
            rows += "\n";

            // END SNIPPET: rows
            resultString = engine
                    .execute(
                            "start n=node(*) where n.name = 'Rita' return n, n.name")
                    .dumpToString();
            System.out.println(resultString);
            columnsString = columns.toString();
            db.shutdown();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void clearDbPath() {
    try {
        deleteRecursively(new File(DB_PATH));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

servlet :(InsertNodes)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    NewCypherQuery ncq=new NewCypherQuery();
    ncq.callAllMethods();
}
```

index.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="InsertNodes">
<input type="text" name="txtname" value="Hello World !!!!!"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Neo4j World"></input> 
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question better? Are you getting an exception, incorrect results, which query?

Comment: when i fire fetchNodes() and debug the method then this statement "result = engine
                .execute("start n=node(*) where n.name = 'Rita' return n, n.name");" then for loop statement does not execute. and result variable return empty iterator.

Comment: when debur pointer go on fetchNodes() method and execute this line "result = engine.execute("start n=node(*) where n.name = 'Rita' return n, n.name");" so result variable return empty iterator. for this reason next line does not execute.

Comment: If you execute the query directly via the Neo4j browser or shell, does it return any results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chauhan,

You shouldn't get any results. You created three nodes, with the names Amad, Pari, and Sona. You then search for a node with the name Rita. There is no node named Rita. You also have a number of other issues with your coding, but Neo4j is doing just what you asked it to do.

Grace and peace,

Jim

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely not sure if I understood your question correctly.

You can only iterate once over a `ExecutionResult`. A subsequent iteration will do nothing since the iterator is already exhausted. This might look strange esp. when you want to log the query results prior to do something with it. Internally Cypher tries to be as memory conservative as possible and tries to avoid to build up collections in favour to directly traverse over the graph while you consume the iterator.

If you want to iterate multiple times you need to populate a collection you can build up a list using e.g. `IteratorUtil.asList`. The result of this is then capable of doing multiple iterations at the cost of memory consumption.